# Change div background color on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div to change background color once a user start to scroll.
I placed what I wrote in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/hectornbl/pen/abLEGPe).
Here is the content of the js file:

```js
function scrollnav() {
var y = document.body.scrollTop();
 if(y>1){
document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
      }
else{   document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "none"; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR, Here is a working js code:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollnav);

function scrollnav() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y > 1) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "unset";
  }
}
```

---

Now let's dive into some educational details:

Simply, your JS function doesn't run. You can confirm that by using `console.log` inside the method and watch the console.

First of all, although it has nothing to do with your problem, there is no `scroll` attribute, but there is an `onscroll` attribute.

Even if you use `onscroll` nothing will change. Because when you scroll the page you don't scroll your `#navbar` element, you scroll the whole `window` so you can remove the method call from your element and add the correct event listener in your JS file:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollnav)
```

Once you confirm your function runs, you will have more meaningful error messages in your console.

To get the top possition, `document.body.scrollTop()` is not a function so you can't call it. I suggest you use `window.scrollY` for best results.

Last but not least, the CSS `background-color` attribute doesn't have a value of `none`, use `unset` or `initial` instead.

Notes:

- even if you add `window.addEventListener` before your function definition, it will still work because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)
- listening to the window scroll event is a costly operation, you should consider throttling or denouncing depending on the application, but it's out of the scope of question

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to set to a color if the scroll of the page is on the top and another color if not

Here is a working exemple.

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if (window.scrollY == 0) {
         document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
         
    }
    else    
    {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue"; 
    }
};
```

```css
   .herodiv{
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  margin 0px;
  padding 0px;
}
.navigation{
  display: flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 0px; 
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body >
    <section class = "hero">
<div class = "herodiv">
    <div id="navbar" class ="navigation" scroll="scrollnav()">
      menu
      section 1
      section 2
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "onScroll" event should be attached to `<body>`. What you do inside the javascript method is where you decide which `<div>` need to get painted. I've put together a small example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <style media="screen">
          #container
          {
              background-color: black;
              min-height: 200vh;
          }
      </style>
      <body onscroll="javascript: changeColor();">
          <div id="container"></div>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function changeColor()
          {
              document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "red";
          }
      </script>
    </html>
```

You can scroll the page and see that the `<div>` is getting the background color changed.

In your **codepen** code, if you move `scroll="scrollnav()"` to `<body>` tag, you can see it working.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

 navbar.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      // handle the scroll event
 });
```